# According to appropriate standards, which Ethernet cable jacket colours should I use?

Tags: ethernet, cabling

We have the following connections.

- User desks to patch panel to non-PoE switch
- CCTV to patch panel to PoE switch
- WiFi access point to Patch panel to PoE switch
- Floodlight to Patch panel to PoE switch
- WAN to patch panel to router

We try to follow existing standards wherever possible, so are trying to discover and follow ethernet jacket colour coding standards. So far, I have been able to find this.

[image: Wire Jacket Colours]

This seems to be the most applicable, however, I do not understand these colour descriptions, as it would appear that none of them are quite fit. I appreciate that this is not specifically for Ethernet.

Questions!

- What is the accepted standard/recommendation for Ethernet jacket colours?
- Can you explain which colours should be used and why according to said standard?

Just to be clear, I am **not seeking opinions**, I am seeking clarification on the accepted standard. We are not interested in [making something up](https://xkcd.com/927/) so evidence based answers only please. If there is no standard, then please say and do not make something up.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129908/discussion-on-question-by-james-geddes-according-to-appropriate-standards-which).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it does not specifically mention Ethernet, ANSI/TIA-606-B-2012 is the "Administration Standard for Telecommunications Infrastructure". It includes the following definition<sup>1</sup>,

> **3.2 Definition of terms**
>
> **cable**: An assembly of one or more insulated conductors or optical fibers, within an enveloping sheath.

This, therefore, includes Ethernet.

The question relates to the termination field of the cable; here this is the front of the patch panel. According to paragraph 10.2.2 of the standard<sup>1</sup>,

> If termination fields are color-coded, the coding shown in table 4 should be used. If a different color-coding scheme is used, it shall be consistent throughout the enterprise. Cross-connections generally connect termination fields of different colors. A summary [...] of these recommendations are shown below in table 4 [...].
>
> **Table 4 - Example of termination field color-coding**
>
> - Termination Type; Color; Pantone #; Typical Application
> - demarcation point; orange; 150C; central office connection
> - network connection; green; 353C; user side of central office connection
> - common equipment; purple; 264C; connection to PBX, mainframe computer
> - Cabling Subsystem 3; white; terminations of building Cabling
> - Subsystem 3; cable connecting MC to ICs
> - Cabling Subsystem 2; gray; 422C; termination of building Cabling
> - Subsystem 2; cable connecting IC to HCs
> - campus cabling; brown; 465C; termination of campus cable between buildings
> - Cabling Subsystem 1; blue; 291C; terminations of Cabling Subsystem 1 cable in TSs
> - miscellaneous; yellow; 101C; alarms, security, or energy management

The wording in this document is quite dense, so to clarify<sup>2</sup>, the following colours should be used.

- **User desks to patch panel to non-PoE switch:**
  Blue
  This is horizontal cabling - any cabling that is used to connect a floor’s wiring closet to wall plates.
- **PoE WiFi access points to Patch panel to PoE switch:**
  Purple
  WiFi access points are common equipment as much as servers and PBXs are.
- **PoE floodlights and PoE CCTV cameras to Patch panel to PoE switch:**
  Yellow
  Security is specifically indicated to fall into the *miscellaneous* category. Best not to confuse CCTV and WiFi.
- **WAN to patch panel to router:**
  Green
  This is the user side of the Internet Service Provider (Central Office<sup>3</sup>) demarcation point<sup>1:3.2, 4</sup>.

If you choose to use a different colour scheme, you must document this and remain consistent throughout the organisation.

Sources:

1. TIA-606-B (Revision of TIA-606-A) Administration Standard for Telecommunications Infrastructure. (2012). [online] Available at: http://az776130.vo.msecnd.net/media/docs/default-source/contractors-and-bidders-library/standards-guidelines/it-standards/tia-606-b.pdf?sfvrsn=2 [Accessed 22 Sep. 2021].
2. NavePoint. (n.d.). ​Cable Color Codes: ANSI/TIA/EIA-606. [online] Available at: https://navepoint.com/blog/cable-color-codes-ansitiaeia606/.
3. Techopedia.com. (n.d.). What is a Central Office (CO)? - Definition from Techopedia. [online] Available at: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/10245/central-office-co [Accessed 22 Sep. 2021].
4. Techopedia.com. (n.d.). What is a Demarcation Point? - Definition from Techopedia. [online] Available at: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/6805/demarcation-point-pod [Accessed 22 Sep. 2021].
   ‌

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129909/discussion-on-answer-by-james-geddes-according-to-appropriate-standards-which-e).